# What is a three-state circuit?

Tags: digital-logic

I have read the Wikipedia article *[Three-state logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-state_logic)*, but it is not clear enough. What is a more simple explanation for what a three-state circuit is?

When and where do we use it? What has CMOS to do with three-state circuits?

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2443/tristate-a-pin

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Normal [push-pull outputs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push%E2%80%93pull_output) drive the output either high or low by turning one of the output transistors on and the other off. Tri-state outputs can turn *both* transistors off, effectively cutting off the output completely. This allows another output on the same wire to drive it either high or low without creating a short circuit between chips.

Tri-state outputs can be implemented with either BJTs or MOSFETs, so there is no *direct* relation between them and CMOS.

Answer (score 0):

Tri-state may be considered as the high impedance state of a digital pin, wich was born to be 0 or 1

(ideally "0" = gnd = short circuit to the ground = very low impedance) ( "1" =  5V [ttl] = short circuit to vcc).

When you define a processor pin as an input, it usually become high impedance (tri state) to listen to the arriving data, may it be a button press or serial data, pulse, whatever.

Comment: Actually trīstate refers to an **output**, with both N and P channel FETs turned off.