# Multiple SPI devices with different logic levels

Tags: spi, level-shifting, logic-level, level-translation

I'm going to use one of the [PIC32MX795F512L](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?product=PIC32MX795F512L) SPI peripherals (master), 1 to 4MHz, to communicate with multiple devices (slaves):

- Wi-Fi module [MRF24WG0MA](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?product=MRF24WG0MA) (3.3V);
- uSD card (3.3V);
- 9 modules with sensors and ADCs with SPI, on their own boards, connected to the main board through 10cm cables (powered by 5.0V from main board);
- 3 external optional modules with sensors and ADCs with SPI, on their own boards, connected to the main board through 25cm cables (powered by 5.0V from main board).

I can only use one SPI in the MCU since all other have their pins already in use. I have enough pins for the CS lines.

The sensor boards can have any ADC with SPI, currently I'm using [MCP3551](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en024597) and [AD7798](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD7798_7799.pdf). If some ADC does not enable the MISO pin only when their CS input is asserted I will use one input buffer (5V) in their respective board for the MISO line, activated with the CS signal.

I will use a resistor in series with the output of the driving device for line termination as described at TI's [LVC Designer's Guide](http://www.ti.com/lit/ml/scba010/scba010.pdf).

For logic level translation I will use:

- Quadruple bus buffers [74AHCT125](http://www.ti.com/product/SN74AHCT125?keyMatch=sn74AHCT125A&tisearch=Search-EN-Everything) for 3.3V to 5.0V in the main board (SCK, CS and MOSI from MCU to the modules ADCs).
- Octal bus transceivers [74LVC245A](http://www.ti.com/product/SN74LVC245A?keyMatch=74LVC245A&tisearch=Search-EN-Everything) in the main board for 5.0V to 3.3V logic level voltage translation, from the modules ADCs MISO pins.

I've never worked with these buffers before. I can't figure if the 74LVC245A has open-collector outputs. Can I join and connect all the 74LVC245A outputs direct to the MCU MISO pin, like I do with MISO pins from 3.3V peripherals?

Edit: added tags.

Comment: Any of these maybe? https://www.flikto.de/collections/breakouts-logic - Similar can be had at other shops too, of course.

Comment: Thanks, but since I'm using SPI I don't need a bi-directional logic-level-converter.

Comment: I imagine you'd only really need a level translator on the MISO line, and then only one as the micro can drive one of the SPI lines directly, CS, SCK and MOSI are all out puts from the micro (I'm assuming the micro is 3.3V) and the 3.3V levels is probably enough to drive 5V SPI inputs. Not pretty, but as a quick hack, it may be fine

Comment: @Tom I'll use one level translator for each MISO because some SPI devices do not enable the MISO only when their CS input is asserted. So I figure by using a level translator for each MISO (enabled by their respective CS line) I wouldn't need to worry about that.
Yes, the micro uses 3.3V. From one of the SPI slaves datasheet, the [MCP3551](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en024597), VIH (CS, SCK) min.=0.7VDD (3.5V). Maybe it also works with 3.3V, but I must make sure it always works.

Comment: Ah, well, in that case, what about tying all the spi devices that use the same levels at the micro directly and just have one full set of level translators for the other rail. That way you're sort of running a single 3.3V SPI master bus and a single master 5V SPI bus, as opposed to each device having it's own translator. Would that be applicable to your system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 74LVC245A has [tri state](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2443/tristate-a-pin) outputs; taking the \$\overline {OE}\$ pin low enables communication from A to B or B to A (depending on the level on the DIR pin).

The outputs can have a state of High, Low and High impedance (Z).

You can therefore *not* tie the outputs together as these are push-pull outputs when enabled.

You could follow the '245A with a multiplexer to use a single pin at the micro.

Comment: Also, look at the first paragraph of the datasheet, it clearly indicates that "OE controls the outputs so that the buses are effectively isolated."

Comment: Thank you. I think I will use the [74LVC125A](http://www.ti.com/product/SN74LVC125A?keyMatch=SN74LVC125&tisearch=Search-EN-Everything)  instead of 74LVC245A, since it has output enable pin for each line (which can be used with the respective CS line).